# Zend framework redirect list urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, zend-framework

I would like to redirect a list of url's inside my Zend Framework 1 application. Now I can add all hundreds of redirects to the htaccess file like this:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html /new-page.html
```

But I rather would like to create an organised file with all redirects. Is this possible? I read something about .ini files but I guess that's not really what i'm looking for.

Something like an array with the old url as key and new url as value would be nice as well. But I'm quite new to the Zend Framework, so maybe someone who can help me out here? Guess I need to create a PHP file and load it in the bootstrap, but I'm quite struggling with that.

EDIT:

Just from the top of my head, something like this would be nice I guess:

rewrites.php

```
$rewrites = array(
    '/old_url.html' => '/new_url.html'
);

if(array_key_exists(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), $rewrites)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ".$rewrites[Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri()]);
}
```

Comment: @D4V1D didn't really try something yet. Don't want to break anything. I'm searching for a way to implement a file with redirects the right way. Because I couldn't find a solution with Google, I thought it would be wise to ask it here. I just edited my answer, I created a quick rewrites.php, now I need to know how to bootstrap it the right way. Any thoughts? Create a new function inside Bootstrap.php perhaps?

Comment: With Apache and mod_rewrite you can make use of the [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive. See exeamples here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/rewritemap.html there is a plain text map.

Comment: @Zimmi guess this wil not work: ```The RewriteMap directive may not be used in <Directory> sections or .htaccess files. You must declare the map in server or virtualhost context. You may use the map, once created, in your RewriteRule and RewriteCond directives in those scopes. You just can't declare it in those scopes.``` I don't have server access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to do there is register a plugin. Said plugin would then inspect incoming requests and if certain criteria are met, redirect the request.

**Library/App/Controller/Plugin/RedirectHandler.php**

```
<?php

class App_Controller_Plugin_RedirectHandler
    extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup
        (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // best to load this from somewhere, but we'll
        // put it here for illustration purposes
        $bindings = array(
            '/old_url.html' => '/new_url.html'
        );

        $uri = $request->getRequestUri();

        if (isset($bindings[$uri])) {
            $this->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($bindings[$uri], 301)
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

And then we need to make sure the handler is called.

**Application/Bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    // ...

    protected function _initControllerPlugins ()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->registerPlugin(new App_Controller_Plugin_RedirectHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Works great. Only had to remove the ```exit;``` from the RedirectHandler.php, cause it returned a blank page.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen Cool. Sorry about that, I was writing from memory and forgot about the response being returned. I've updated it now. The `exit` is actually important, otherwise the request still continues. What you need is `->sendResponse()` after the `->setRedirect(...)`.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Just replaced the $bindings variable so it loads a json file with all redirects. Works great: ```$bindings = json_decode(file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH."/configs/rewrites.json"), true);``` Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen no problem. `JSON` is a good option, but if this list gets long, you might wanna think about loading it in with a `require` and setting the list up as a PHP array instead. Means no need to read and parse the `JSON`, so might shave off a millisecond or two :-)